# Alignment in a 32 Bit RAM

Tags: ram

I have a Question in terms of alignment. I learned in my Computer Architecture module that a Data package of n Byte is in the adress m aligned if function m mod n=0 is valid. Now if I have understood how reading a RAM works correctly:
supposing we have a 32 Bit architecture. This could be built with 4 memory banks each holding 2^30 Bit and every neighboured Byte is in the next Bank. Why can't I store a 2 Byte package at adress 1 (1 mod 2=1). I should be able to read the package within one reading operation.

Comment: All memory banks will receive the same address information via lines a2 to a29. The low two bits of the address will not be used to select the address in the memory modules.

Comment: @freezeling - similar: [How processor read memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132553/how-processor-read-memory)